# Matplotlib 3d Bar charts

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a 3d bar chart for personal interest in Matplotlib. From what I can see, it is not well supported and mayavi is a preferred route, but I'm not sure what I want is achievable.

[image: Matplotlib plot]

My plot above obviously has the clipping/rendering error that is mentioned in a few places, and I've tried using `zsort='max'` to fix it but without luck.

My issue is further compounded. For any individual bar, we need too decide whether our position is good, in danger, or very bad (green, red, yellow) based on some criteria obtained from a separate data frame.

So, for example, `df` is a 6x6 data frame with the values we want to plot. We have a second data frame, `dft`, which contains the conditionals to decide if we plot green, amber, or red.

I'm currently doing this by:

```
greens[:]=np.NAN
ambers[:]=np.NAN
reds[:]=np.NAN
for loca in range(len(values)):
    x_idx=np.where(xlabels==names[loca].split(':')[0])[0][0]
    y_idx=np.where(ylabels==names[loca].split(':')[1])[0][0]

    if bank_share[loca]<=0.05:
        greens[x_idx][y_idx]=values[loca]
        greens[y_idx][x_idx]=values[loca]
    elif bank_share[loca]<=0.07:
        ambers[x_idx][y_idx]=values[loca]
        ambers[y_idx][x_idx]=values[loca]
    else:
        reds[x_idx][y_idx]=values[loca]
        reds[y_idx][x_idx]=values[loca]

zvalsg=greens.ravel()
zvalsa=ambers.ravel()
zvalsr=reds.ravel()
ax.bar3d(xposM.ravel(),yposM.ravel(), zvalsg*0, dx, dy, zvalsg, color='g', zsort='max')
ax.bar3d(xposM.ravel(),yposM.ravel(), zvalsa*0, dx, dy, zvalsa, color='y', zsort='max')
ax.bar3d(xposM.ravel(),yposM.ravel(), zvalsr*0, dx, dy, zvalsr, color='r', zsort='max')
```

Can someone suggest how I fix my matplotlib plot, or how I can use Mayavi to do it? Fromw hat I've seen, my concerns with Mayavi are being able to lavel the axis ticks as I have here with matplotlib, and my ability to impose multiple plots on top of each other?

Thank you so much!